# launch a function for the map on screen load. iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, maps

I am trying to launch the map automatically when the screen loads.

Can this be done? Launch this function on view did appear.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    if let anno = view.annotation {
        let place = MKPlacemark(coordinate: anno.coordinate)
        let destination = MKMapItem(placemark: place)
        destination.name = "Vehicle Sighting"
        let regionDistance: CLLocationDistance = 1000
        let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(anno.coordinate, regionDistance, regionDistance)

        let options = [MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue (mkCoordinate: regionSpan.center), MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span), MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving] as [String : Any]

        MKMapItem.openMaps(with: [destination], launchOptions: options)
    }
}
```

Comment: You wouldn't launch *that function*. You could create a map item and open it. It would be strange to do in `viewDidAppear` as the user experience would be a new view appearing and then the maps app opening. It would be more sensible to open maps from the previous view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this function, you only need to pass the coordinates and place name, this works, I use this in several projects

```
static func openMapsAppWithLocation(coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D,placeName:String)
{
    let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 10000
    let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regionDistance, regionDistance)
    let options = [
        MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(mkCoordinate: regionSpan.center),
        MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span)
    ]
    let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
    let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    mapItem.name = placeName
    mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: options)
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This worked a charm @Reinier, Thank you for this I could implement this int eh controller before with no need to load a new view with map on it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @TonyMerritt You only need a name and a coordinate, you don't need load a map or even UIViewController, I use this code in my AppManager singleton as static func as you can see and works just perfect

Comment: Yes That was a better outcome than I was looking for It was messy to go to another controller to load a map view and then go to maps from that. this way was perfect.

Comment: @TonyMerritt I am Glad that helps you, happy coding and best regards!

Answer (score 0):

an alternative version using @Reinier answer.

this shows how it was implemented into an action the view controller before with no need to go to the next controller to launch in view did load. Also how i got the coordinates from a postcode

```
var addressCode = [[String: Double]]()


@IBAction func onMapPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let address = postCode
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) {
            placemarks, error in
            let placemark = placemarks?.first
            let lat = placemark?.location?.coordinate.latitude
            let lon = placemark?.location?.coordinate.longitude
            //          let locationTitle = self.places]
            let latLon = ["latitude":lat!, "longitude": lon!]
            self.addressCode.append(latLon)

            for location in self.addressCode {
                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location["latitude"]!, longitude: location["longitude"]!)


                self.openMapsAppWithLocation(coordinates: annotation.coordinate, placeName: self.makeLabel.text!)
    }
}
}
```